# Removing `{{` in angular

Tags: javascript, php, angularjs, laravel

I am using Laravel framework..

I can't able to use `{{` symbol inside (As laravel consider's its as outputing )

I tried this code use interpolateProvider.. ie., to use `<%` instead of `{{` in `angularjs` in single angualr js file. but how can i do this in my .run function or config file ?

```
  var sampleApp = angular.module('sampleApp', [], function($interpolateProvider) {
        $interpolateProvider.startSymbol('<%');
        $interpolateProvider.endSymbol('%>');
    });
```

Here is my `app.js`

```
 var app = angular.module('myApp', ['ngRoute', 'ngAnimate', 'toaster']);

 app.config(['$routeProvider',
     function($routeProvider) {
         $routeProvider.
         when('/login', {
                 title: 'Login',
                 templateUrl: 'resources/views/layout/login.php',
                 controller: 'authCtrl'
             })
             .when('/', {
                 title: 'Login',
                 templateUrl: 'resources/views/layout/login-ang.php',
                 controller: 'authCtrl',
                 role: '0'
             })
             .when('/invalidtoken', {
                 title: 'Login',
                 templateUrl: 'resources/views/layout/invalidtoken.php',
                 controller: 'authCtrl',
                 role: '0'
             })
     }
 ])

 .run(function($rootScope, $location, Data, $http) {
     $rootScope.$on("$routeChangeStart", function(event, next, current) {
         $http.post('resources/views/layout/calls/checkSession.php', {}).then(function(results) {
             function($rootScope, $location) {
                 $rootScope.this_route = function() {
                     return $location.path().replace('/', '');
                 };
             };
         });
     });
 });
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Within the config function of angular in app.js

```
    var app = angular.module('myApp', ['ngRoute', 'ngAnimate', 'toaster']);

  // inject interpolateProvider into config
  app.config(['$routeProvider', '$interpolateProvider',
  function ($routeProvider, $interpolateProvider) {

    $interpolateProvider.startSymbol('<%');
    $interpolateProvider.endSymbol('%>');

    $routeProvider.
      when('/login', {
        title: 'Login',
        templateUrl: 'resources/views/layout/login.php',
        controller: 'authCtrl'
      })
      .when('/', {
        title: 'Login',
        templateUrl: 'resources/views/layout/login-ang.php',
        controller: 'authCtrl',
        role: '0'
      })
      .when('/invalidtoken', {
        title: 'Login',
        templateUrl: 'resources/views/layout/invalidtoken.php',
        controller: 'authCtrl',
        role: '0'
      })
  }
]);
```

Then within your template you use:

```
<h1><% my_angular_expression %></h1>
```

Comment: Is my config function this .. `var app = angular.module('myApp', ['ngRoute', 'ngAnimate', 'toaster']);` or `app.config(['$routeProvider',
    function ($routeProvider) {` ?

Comment: Please edit your question and provide the code of your app.js so I can read it

Comment: Here this works for me ;) `var app = angular.module('myApp', ['ngRoute', 'ngAnimate', 'toaster'],  function($interpolateProvider) {
        $interpolateProvider.startSymbol('<%');
        $interpolateProvider.endSymbol('%>');
    } );`

Comment: Yes but I am showing you the min safe way. Your way would break in your uglify your code. Thats why it is recommended to specify your dependencies in an array like that as Strings don't get uglified

Comment: here is a link to read more about minsafe best practices in angular if you like: http://thegreenpizza.github.io/2013/05/25/building-minification-safe-angular.js-applications/ and please accept the answer if you found it useful